# Material selection list without checbox but list element is highlighted - looking for example

Tags: angular, list, angular-material

I found example of material selection list:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-qhyxd5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

It's pretty fine, but i need to make something like highlight when one or more rows are selected.
At first i need to hide checkbox, and second need to style background of selected row. Somebody know how, have knowledge about example or can guide me to answer?

Comment: Have you tried to change above example yourself, according to your requirement?

Comment: Tried `:host {
      ::ng-deep.mat-pseudo-checkbox{
        display: none !important;
      }` but checkbox is still visible. ngClass is good option to show which rows are selected, but no idead how to hide checkboxes
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` for option list:

HTML:

```
[ngClass]="{'special-class': selectedOptions.includes(filter.value) }"
```

CSS:

```
.special-class{
  background-color: red;  -- to set the background color
  pointer-events: none; -- to disable user clicks
}
```

Comment: Your idea is good to use ngClass, but how to hide checkboxes?

Comment: @Yamdi You can disable the click events!

Comment: But checkbox is always visible

Answer (score 0):

To hide checkboxes, just use:

```
.mat-pseudo-checkbox{
  display: none !important;
}
```